# How to sort a list of binary strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

let's say for example I have a list of binary codes such as this:

```
a=['100','10','01010','000','0001','10001']
```

I want the sorted list to be:

```
a=['000','0001','10','100','01010','10001']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function `int` as a key:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x, 2))
# ['000', '0001', '10', '100', '01010', '10001']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['100','10','01010','000','0001','10001']
list=[bin(int(ele)) for ele in a]
list=[int(ele,0) for ele in list]

print(sorted(list))
```

output

```
[0, 1, 10, 100, 1010, 10001]
```